# modal with dynamic content won't set value to text field

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm loading content into a modal, and using checkbox's to set email addresses to a "recipients" text field.  If I hard code the content, this works fine... but loading it from an external resource, the checked email addresses don't populate the recipients field.

I realize the post here isn't going load my local resource for the dynamic content, so I've had to double-up the code.... first is my real code, and then the way that it does work.

> **Original**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.openContacts').on('click', function() {
    $('.modal-body').load('modalcontacts', function() {
      $('#contactsModal').modal({
        show: true
      });
    });
  });

  $('#contactsearch').hideseek({
    highlight: true,
    nodata: 'No results found'
  });

  $(':checkbox[name="addcontact"]').change(function() {
    var assignedTo = $(':checkbox[name="addcontact"]:checked').map(function() {
        return this.id;
      })
      .get();
    $("input[name='recipients']").val(assignedTo.join("; "));
  });
  /*
   * form validator
   */
  $('#ci-form').validator();
  /*
   * TinyMCE WYSIWYG Editor
   */
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    theme: 'modern',
    plugins: 'autosave code paste print preview searchreplace autolink directionality visualblocks visualchars image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor imagetools contextmenu colorpicker textpattern',
    paste_data_images: true,
    branding: false,
    skin: "lightgray",
    height: 300
  });
});
```

```css
.modal-body {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
    <input type="text" name="recipients" value="" id="recipients" maxlength="" class="form-control" placeholder="Email to">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactsModal" class="btn btn-info openContacts" type="button">Contacts</button>
                          </span>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- Contacts Modal -->
<div id="contactsModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <input id="contactsearch" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." type="text" data-list=".contactlist" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Loading....</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.6.7/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vdw/HideSeek/master/jquery.hideseek.min.js"></script>
```

> **Should work like this**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.openContacts').on('click', function() {
    $('.modal-body').load('modalcontacts', function() {
      $('#contactsModal').modal({
        show: true
      });
    });
  });

  $('#contactsearch').hideseek({
    highlight: true,
    nodata: 'No results found'
  });

  $(':checkbox[name="addcontact"]').change(function() {
    var assignedTo = $(':checkbox[name="addcontact"]:checked').map(function() {
        return this.id;
      })
      .get();
    $("input[name='recipients']").val(assignedTo.join("; "));
  });
  /*
   * form validator
   */
  $('#ci-form').validator();
  /*
   * TinyMCE WYSIWYG Editor
   */
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    theme: 'modern',
    plugins: 'autosave code paste print preview searchreplace autolink directionality visualblocks visualchars image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor imagetools contextmenu colorpicker textpattern',
    paste_data_images: true,
    branding: false,
    skin: "lightgray",
    height: 300
  });
});
```

```css
.modal-body {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
    <input type="text" name="recipients" value="" id="recipients" maxlength="" class="form-control" placeholder="Email to">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
   <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactsModal" class="btn btn-info openContacts" type="button">Contacts</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Contacts Modal -->
<div id="contactsModal" class="modal fade in" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <input id="contactsearch" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." type="text" data-list=".contactlist" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="contactlist">
          <h3>A</h3>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Aaron Aaberg</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="aaron.aaberg@somewebsite.com" value="aaron.aaberg@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">aaron.aaberg@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Aaron Aaby</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="aaron.aaby@somewebsite.com" value="aaron.aaby@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">aaron.aaby@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Abbey Aadland</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="abbey.aadland@somewebsite.com" value="abbey.aadland@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">abbey.aadland@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Abbie Aagaard</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="abbie.aagaard@somewebsite.com" value="abbie.aagaard@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">abbie.aagaard@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Abby Aakre</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="abby.aakre@somewebsite.com" value="abby.aakre@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">abby.aakre@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Abdul Aaland</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="abdul.aaland@somewebsite.com" value="abdul.aaland@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">abdul.aaland@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Abe Aalbers</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="abe.aalbers@somewebsite.com" value="abe.aalbers@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">abe.aalbers@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Abel Aalderink</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="abel.aalderink@somewebsite.com" value="abel.aalderink@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">abel.aalderink@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Abigail Aalund</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="abigail.aalund@somewebsite.com" value="abigail.aalund@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">abigail.aalund@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Abraham Aamodt</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="abraham.aamodt@somewebsite.com" value="abraham.aamodt@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">abraham.aamodt@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Abram Aamot</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="abram.aamot@somewebsite.com" value="abram.aamot@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">abram.aamot@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Ada Aanderud</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="ada.aanderud@somewebsite.com" value="ada.aanderud@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">ada.aanderud@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Adah Aanenson</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="adah.aanenson@somewebsite.com" value="adah.aanenson@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">adah.aanenson@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Adalberto Aanerud</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="adalberto.aanerud@somewebsite.com" value="adalberto.aanerud@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">adalberto.aanerud@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Alda Abdo</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="alda.abdo@somewebsite.com" value="alda.abdo@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">alda.abdo@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Alden Abdon</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="alden.abdon@somewebsite.com" value="alden.abdon@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">alden.abdon@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Aldo Abdool</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="aldo.abdool@somewebsite.com" value="aldo.abdool@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">aldo.abdool@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Alena Abdulmuniem</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="alena.abdulmuniem@somewebsite.com" value="alena.abdulmuniem@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">alena.abdulmuniem@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3>B</h3>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Bob Smith</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="bob.smith@somewebsite.com" value="bob.smith@somewebsite.com" name="addcontact">bob.smith@somewebsite.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h3>C</h3>
          <div class="list-group">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <strong class="list-group-item-heading">Carl Grimes</strong>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">
                <span class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="carl.grimes@gmail.com" value="carl.grimes@gmail.com" name="addcontact">carl.grimes@gmail.com</label></span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.6.7/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vdw/HideSeek/master/jquery.hideseek.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I have to bind an event to a parent that already existed before the document was loaded.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.openContacts').on('click', function() {
    $('.modal-body').load("modalcontacts", function() {
      console.log("loaded");
      $('#contactsModal').modal({
        show: true
      });
    });
  });


  $(document).on('mouseover mouseout', '.contactlist', function() {
    $('#contactsearch').hideseek({
      nodata: 'No results found'
    });

    $(':checkbox[name="addcontact"]').change(function() {
      var assignedTo = $(':checkbox[name="addcontact"]:checked').map(function() {
          return this.id;
        })
        .get();
      $("input[name='recipients']").val(assignedTo.join("; "));

    });
  });
});
```