# Dynamically created element doesn't open bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have an MVC View that has a table and in one of his cell it contains an anchor tag who opens a Bootstrap modal like this:

```
<td><a href="#" class="button-action btnUpdateModal" name="btnUpdateModal">Edit</a></td>
```

This works with this JS:

```
   var updateModal = $("#updateHolidayModal");
   $(".btnUpdateModal").click(function () {
        let hId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id').split('-')[1];
        let hName = "";
        let hDate = "";
        let hWai;
        let hEH;
        let hG;
        var $row = jQuery(this).closest('tr');
        var $columns = $row.find('td');
        jQuery.each($columns, function (i, item) {
            if (i == 0) {
                hName = item.innerHTML;
            } else if (i == 1) {
                hDate = item.innerHTML;
            } else if (i == 2) {
                hWai = $(this).attr("class") == "true" ? true : false;
            } else if (i == 3) {
                hEH = item.innerHTML == "@Resource.Yes" ? true : false;
            } else if (i == 4) {
                hG = item.innerHTML == "@Resource.Yes" ? true : false;
            }

        });

        $("#hNameUpdate").val(hName);
        $("#hDateUpdate").val(hDate);
        $("#hEHUpdate").prop('checked', hEH);
        $("#hWaiUpdate").prop('checked', hWai);
        
        $(".hdnHId").val(hId);
        updateModal.modal('show');
    });
```

When the controllers render this view, the modal work smoothly, but I have to make a filter for this table, and for that I'm using AJAX. I already managed to delete the rows and create new with the JSON returned by another action in the controller, but I cannot make work the anchors tag (Edit and Delete)

```
$("#btnFiltrarPorFecha").click(function () {

        let startDate = $('#datefilterh').data("daterangepicker").startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
        let endDate = $('#datefilterh').data("daterangepicker").endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY');

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetHJson", "Hol")',
            data: { 'startDate': startDate, 'endDate': endDate },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#principalTable tbody").remove();
                let editAction = '<td><a href="#" class="button-action btnUpdateModal"  name="btnUpdateModal">Edit</a></td>';
                let deleteAction = '<td><a class="button-action btnDeleteModal" name="btnDeleteModal">Delete</a></td>';
                let date = "";
                let waiElement = "";                
                let tEHElement = "";
                let t = "<tbody>";
                $.each(response, function (i, v) {
                    date = moment(v.inicioF).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
                    if (v.ren == true) {
                        waiElement = '<td class="true"><span class="wai-true">Yes</span></td>';
                    } else {
                        waiElement = '<td class="false"><span class="wai-false">No</span></td>';
                    }
                    if (v.tEH) {
                        tEHElement = '<td>Yes</td>';
                    } else {
                        tEHElement = '<td>No</td>';
                    }
                    t += '<tr style="text-align:center;" id="' + v.idF + '"><td>' + v.descripcionF + '</td><td>' + date + '</td>' + waiElement + tEHElement + editAction + deleteAction + '</tr> ';
                });
                t += "</tbody>";
                $("#principalTable").append(t);
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
    })
```

The render is okay, and the element in the inspector seems right, but when I click on the anchor tag it doesn't open the modal.

Why is the modal not opening?

Comment: When you're dealing with dynamic elements, you have to bind to a parent that already existed.  Here's a  similar question I had a few years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48030352/2844703

Comment: I'm not used to work with frontend development. Can u explain to me how to apply this to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment of James, I resolved the problem like this.

```
$("#principalTable").on('click', '.btnUpdateModal', function() { 
    // do something here
});
```

Where:

- #principalTable: is the id of my table. This is not created dynamically but is created when the view is loaded.
- click: is the event that I'm waiting to happen
- btnUpdateModal: is the class I'm adding dynamically to the elements that I want to execute the event click.